# How to make progress bar invisible after load image?

Tags: android-studio, android-progressbar, chrome-app-developer-tool

When my app is installed I want to see a progress bar until the image is loaded by an API call. After that, I want to make it invisible.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView imageView;

// ...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    loud();
}

private void loud(){
    setProgressBarVisibility(true);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            String url= null;
            try {
                url = response.getString("url");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setProgressBarVisibility(false);
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("ERROR ","Error ");
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```